# Change QComboBox item text in delegate

Tags: c++, qt, combobox

I want to change the color and the text of items displayed by a `QComboBox`, depending on some conditions, but without changing the data in the model itself.

I figured out how to change the color, which was rather easy:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void
ComboPriorityDelegate::paint(QPainter* p_painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& p_option, const QModelIndex& p_index) const
{
    QStyleOptionViewItem newOption(p_option);
    // Set the color
    newOption.palette.setColor(QPalette::Text, QColor(255, 0, 0));

    QItemDelegate::paint(p_painter, newOption, p_index);
}
```

Just to explain, in my actual code, I have some conditions there, so I do not want to modify **each** item.

However, I cannot figure out how I would change the displayed text. I tried setting the **`text`** property of the **`newOption`**, but it seems like that has nothing to do with the actual text being displayed.

In addition, I need to change the text back to its original form as soon as the item is selected.

I found out that `p_index.data().toString()` gives me the displayed text, but that doesn't help me modifying it. What I need is an easy way to modify the text attribute of the `QLabel` (or whatever the `QComboBox` uses to display item text), without affecting the model itself.

I know that there would be workarounds, like remove the item from the combo box that I want to change and inserting a changed version, but I hope that there is an easier way.

Comment: Why do you want to change the item text in your delegate's `paint()` method?

Comment: I'd gladly do it somewhere else in the delegate if that is possible. I tried the setEditorData function, but that is only called when the mouse hovers over the item. I need to change the text and the color of the items as soon as the the list opens. It would just be more elegant if both was possible inside the same function. But it is not a requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Actual Answer:**
It seems that what I want to do is simply not possible just using a delegate.

**Workaround:**
So what I did instead was using an event filter to set the correct suffix for the item texts as well as their color before the drop-down opens (listen to `MousePressed` event).

And to make sure that the text suffix is removed when an item is selected, I added a slot to the event filter class that must be connected to the `activated()` signal of the `QComboBox`. That slot then checks for the suffix and removes it.

This is not a nice thing, but at least it requires only one additional class and two lines of code to make use of. And it should be independent of the data model used.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a proxy model on top of your model and changing its `data()` method seems the easiest solution to me.
There is [QIdentityProxyModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qidentityproxymodel.html) which you can simply subclass and override `data()`. Use your original model as the proxy model's source, and the proxy model as the combobox's model.

Comment: That is a possible solution, yes. But also requires the creation of a new class just for that purpose. And it requires getting the original model, and overwriting the model of the ComboBox. I have found an own solution by now, which is very different, probably even less elegant, but also works. I will post it tomorrow.

Comment: I just noticed that this is probably not a solution as I need to change the text back to its original form as soon as the item is selected. I doubt that this is possible with the proxy. I updated the description.

Comment: @TheSHEEEP: Ah, if the text changes dynamically depending on the selection, using a proxy is indeed not the best way. Sure you could hack that together by listening to selection changed signals in the proxy and emitting dataChanged() accordingly, but that is ugly (the model should not know about selection and therefore the view)